# connect to asp.net sql server on server with android

Tags: android, asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a website with ASP.Net and SQLserver 2008 database on host
and I have a android application.
I want to connect to SQL database in my android app and call store procedure.
when i insert data to database with website on host , i want to show last data in android app

help me please.

Comment: do you have any questions?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is using API.

You need to create API in your website using ASP.NET to retrieve data in for example json/XML format and then read and show it in your android app.

for creating api in asp.net
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

for consuming it from android app

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/calling-restful-services-from-your-android-app/